# Different class / struct conform indexOf

Tags: arrays, swift

I have two different classes / struct and I want to be able to use:

```
let index = [T].indexOf(U)
```

Some sample data for playground:

```
struct Foo: Hashable {
    let name: String
    var hashValue: Int { return name.hashValue }
}

struct Bar: Hashable {
    let name: String
    var hashValue: Int { return name.hashValue }
}

func ==(lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool { return lhs.name == rhs.name }
func ==(lhs: Bar, rhs: Bar) -> Bool { return lhs.name == rhs.name }
func ==(lhs: Bar, rhs: Foo) -> Bool { return lhs.name == rhs.name }
```

Attempts:

```
let test1 = Foo(name: "John")
let test2 = Foo(name: "Amy")
let test3 = Bar(name: "Mary")
let test4 = Bar(name: "John")

let arrays = [test1, test2]
let result = arrays.indexOf(test3) // cannot convert value of type 'Bar' to expected argument type 'Foo'
```

Should I just use a protocol instead?

---

Using protocols:

```
protocol Names {
    var name: String { get set }
}

extension Equatable where Self: Names { }

struct Foo: Names { var name: String }
struct Bar: Names { var name: String }

func ==<T: Names>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool { 
    return lhs.name == rhs.name 
}
```

Attempts:

```
let arrays: [Names] = [test1, test2]
let result = arrays.indexOf(test2) // cannot convert value of type 'Foo' to expected argument type '@noescape (Names) throws -> Bool'
```

---

And:

```
protocol Names: Equatable {
    var name: String { get set }
}

let arrays: [Foo] = [test1, test2]
let result = arrays.indexOf(test3) // cannot convert value of type 'Bar' to expected argument type 'Foo'
```

Comment: I know maybe this is not what you want but you can always do `arrays.indexOf({ $0 == test3 })`

Comment: Yes, I know that's possible. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the definition of the operator overload for `Equatable` is:

```
func ==(_ lhs: Self, _ rhs: Self) -> Bool
```

Therefore it is contained to the type of object it is operating upon - in your case `Foo` or `Bar`, but not a mix of both. The following declaration will never be used by `Equatable`:

```
func ==(lhs: Bar, rhs: Foo) -> Bool { return lhs.name == rhs.name }
```

Can you change your structs to classes that subclass a common ancestor? Along the lines of:

```
class FooBar: Hashable {
    var name: String!
    var hashValue: Int { return name.hashValue }
    init() { }
}


class Foo: FooBar {
}

class Bar: FooBar {
}

func ==(lhs: FooBar, rhs: FooBar) -> Bool { return lhs.name == rhs.name }

var test1 = Foo(); test1.name = "John"
var test2 = Foo(); test2.name = "Amy"
var test3 = Bar(); test3.name = "Mary"
var test4 = Bar(); test4.name = "John"

let arrays: [FooBar] = [test1, test2]
let result = arrays.indexOf(test4)
print(result)
```

Comment: This information is very useful for me, but unfortunately the classes already inherits from `NSManagedObject` so I can't use this method.